# How to add a zip file to zip file using C# and DotNetZip

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am using DotNetZip (http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to build Zip files on the fly.  I would like to be able to create a ZIP file in code and then add it to another ZIP file in code.  Will this work?  My code is below.  I am trying to use a MemoryStream to hold the internal zip file and then add that memory stream to the main zip file.  I'm not sure if this is correct.  When I try this, my internal zip file has zero bytes and it fails when I try to open up the resulting main zip file.

```
using (ZipFile _mainZip = new ZipFile())
{
  using (ZipFile _internalZip = new ZipFile())
  {
    ..add stuff to the internal zip..
    MemoryStream _myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    _internalZip.Save(_myMemoryStream);
    _mainZip.AddEntry("myTitle.zip", _myMemoryStream);
  }
}
_mainZip.Save("myZip.zip");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the MemoryStream's position is at the end of the stream.
You could try to set it to the begining:

```
_myMemoryStream.Position = 0;
```

That might work.